# How can I access form parameters from an interceptor on a JAX-RS service?

Tags: java, rest, cxf, jax-rs, interceptor

I need to access html form parameters processed by JAX-RS in an interceptor defined as follows:

```
@Interceptor
@InterceptThis
public class MyInterceptor{
    @AroundInvoke
    public Object process(InvocationContext context) throws Exception{
        //I need to access form parameters here!

        return context.proceed();
    }
}
```

I've tried injecting an HttpServletRequest and extracting it from there but the parameters are not available, they seem to have been consumed by the JAX-RS framework.  I can use @FormParam to inject the values into the method call in my service class but I can't do that in the interceptor.

Is there any way to access form parameters from an interceptor after the JAX-RS implementation has already read them?

I am using Apache CXF on TomEE.

Comment: If you already have the `@FormParam`s in the resource method. you can obtain them through [`context.getParameters()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/interceptor/InvocationContext.html#getParameters%28%29)

Comment: @peeskillet The idea was that the interceptor would read the parameters but the resource method would not necessarily need to know about it, so I'm not actually using `@FormParam` on the resource method.  I managed to get it working with a GET request by declaring `@Context UriInfo uirInfo` on the interceptor but I still can't figure out how to do it with form parameters sent in as POST.

Comment: Your solution is not really a solution, but a work-around, that forces you to completely change the API. This might not be desirable. A GET request should not mean the same thing (from a REST standpoint) as a POST request. I don't have the complete solution you are looking for, but for me, if I had to choose between changing the API from POST to GET, and adding the form param in the method signature, I would choose the latter. Just something to think about.

Comment: @peeskillet It's definitely a workaround which I'd like to avoid although I'd also like to avoid having to change the signature of every method the interceptor is applied to.  But I agree that it's better to keep the workaround tucked away in the backend than to change the API, it was more an experimentation than a solution.